# PHP - Open TXT file, add +1 to contents when link clicked

Tags: php

How can I make it so when a user clicks on a link on my web page, it writes to a .txt file named "Count.txt", which contains only a number and adds 1 to that number?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? It sounds like you just want to log your visitors. There are many other things that may suit your purposes better, such as AwStats or Google Analytics.

Comment: What I am trying to do is keep track of how many times a program of mine is downloaded.  I've never used MySQL or anything and have basic PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you forego any validity checking you could do it with something as simple as:

```
file_put_contents($theCounterFile, file_get_contents($theCounterFile)+1);
```

**Addition:**

There's talk about concurrency in this thread and it should be noted that it is a good idea to use a database and transactions to deal with concurrency, I'd highly recommend against writing a bunch of plumbing code to do this in a file.

If you've ever had, or think you might ever have two requests for the resource in the same second you should look into [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) with [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com), or PDO with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) instead of a file, use transactions (and [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb.html) or better if you're going for mysql).

But really, even if you get two requests in the same microsecond (highly unlikely), chances of locking the file are slim as it will not be kept open and the two requests will probably not be handled parallel enough to lock anyway. Reality check: how many hits on the same resource do you get on average in the same minute?...

Comment: This will fail when multiple users connect at the same time, you need locks. See Wim Vandersmissen's answer.

Comment: yes it will fail, if you need something viable for concurrency use a database, not a text file.

Comment: You forgot the specify the filename for `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to do anything more advanced, like say two numbers, you may want to consider using SQLite.  It's about as about as fast and as simple as opening and closing a file, but is much more flexible.

Comment: SQLite is very obviously a much better idea than using a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is quite easy:

```
$count = (int)file_get_contents('/path/to/Count.txt');
file_put_contents('/path/to/Count.txt', $count++, LOCK_EX);
```

But you'll run into concurrency problems using this code. One way to generate a lock safe from any race condition is:

```
$countFile = '/path/to/Count.txt';
$countTemp = tempnam(dirname($countFile), basename($countFile));
$countLock = $countFile . '.lock';
$f_lock = fopen($countLock, 'w'); 
if(flock($f_lock, LOCK_EX)) {
    $currentCount = (int)file_get_contents($countFile);
    $f_temp = fopen($countTemp, 'w');
    if(flock($f_temp, LOCK_EX)) {
        fwrite($f_temp, $currentCount++); 
        flock($f_temp, LOCK_UN); 
        fclose($f_temp); 
        if(!rename($countTemp, $countFile)) { 
            unlink($countTemp); 
        } 
    }
    flock($f_lock, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($f_lock); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, lock the file (VERY important), read the number currently in there, add 1 to the number, write number back to file, release the lock and close the file.

ie. something like :

```
$fp = fopen("count.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // do an exclusive lock
    $num = fread($fp, 10);
    $num++;
    fseek($fp, 0);
    fwrite($fp, $num);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
} else {
    // handle error
}
fclose($fp);
```

should work (not tested).

Comment: why on earth would you want to write all that plumbing yourself, just to reqd and write an int?

Comment: Because on a website you will have concurrent access to the file, and your counter will be off or corrupted if you don't lock and unlock the file.